# Add additional existing records to a nested form using AJAX and Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm writing a form with nested attributes in Rails 4.  I need to add an existing record to a list within a nested form, but I don't know how to preserve the `f` builder from the parent form, after the ajax call.  Is there a way to write this into the session?

Please, for clarity, I am not adding a new empty record, but an existing record, which the user can proceed to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the controller works.

`@f = ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(:object, @customer, view_context, {})`

And then in the js.erb file

`$("some-div").html("<%= j render('some_partial', f: @f) %>");`